# MATLAB: Rewriting same operations on 2 Structures without a loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, struct

Given matrix `M` (x times 5) and structure `thr`, which contains numbers, how can I do following procedure without a loop?

Using `structfun` is not possible with 2 structures. Using `arrayfun` is not possible to assign to my structure `index`. Also `cellfun` is not the right one. Anyone any help?

Thank you in advance!

```
index.b = M(:,1) >= thr.b;
index.c = M(:,2) >= thr.c;
index.h = M(:,3) >= thr.h;
index.r = M(:,4) >= thr.r;
index.s = M(:,5) >= thr.s;
```

Comment: Maybe a struct is not the best data structure for this? Why not `I = M > T` where `T(:, 1) = thr.b` etc...?

Comment: Thanks @Dan, the idea is not bad. But it does not calc the same as above. The link to each columns to `M` is lost. Should be `M(:,1) > T(1)`

Comment: no I was suggesting that `size(M) == size(T)` so `T = repmat([thr.b, thr.c, thr.h,...], size(M, 1), 1)` for example

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to maintain your data structures as they are here is a solution.

First, let's create dummy input:

```
M = rand(5);
index = struct('b',[],'c',[],'h',[],'r',[],'s',[]);
thr = struct('b',.5,'c',.5,'h',.5,'r',.5,'s',.5);
```

Here is the actual trick:

```
A = bsxfun(@ge, M, [thr.b, thr.c, thr.h, thr.r, thr.s]);
A = num2cell(A,1);
[index.b, index.c, index.h, index.r, index.s] = deal(A{:});
```

Again, you can do this in a more efficient way using adequate data structures.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, @upperBound, what would the adequate data structures be? Do you mean the way Dan showed in the previous answer?